# error while executing "make" on terminal

Tags: c++, command-line, terminal, makefile

I am a bit newbie to using terminal so I will appreaciate it a lot if you help me to sort this out.

This small folder named mismatch came with the code I downloaded,which is supposed take four arguments like this

> ./mismatch/mismatch 3 1 ${SFILE}

and compute mismatch scores for protein sequences. Folder  'mismatch' contains mismatchManager.cc, makefile and a folder named "CVS".

inside the makefile,

```
all:  mismatchManager.cc    
      g++ mismatchManager.cc -o ../../bin/mismatch -lm
```

After a quick search, I found out that -o is used when you want to name your .exe file and -lm is used to link the executable to a library which  I thought is "bin" here. So when I ran "make" command from the terminal, it gave the following error.

```
ld: can't open output file for writing: ../../bin/mismatch, errno=2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I thought that "bin" directory could be /usr/local/bin where the executables are stored so, I replaced the above path to this one, however it gave the same error. Here there is a solution for ErrNo=21 [Why does the name of a source file affect compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200521/why-does-the-name-of-a-source-file-affect-compilation), as it is told I don't have a folder named mismatchManager though.

I also changed make file into

```
all:  mismatchManager.cc    
      g++ -o mismatch mismatchManager.cc
```

then ran "make" command. It worked well, then I copied to mismatch.exe to /usr/local/bin manually. This time I was able to pass arguments but I didn't produce any results. I have no idea what I should do.

Thanks already!

Comment: "I don't have a folder named mismatchManager though." - your output file is `mismatch`

Comment: yes, it is. I didn't understand the point you made.

Comment: The fact that you don't have a folder named `mismatchManager` is irrelevant, since that isn't what you are trying to name your output file.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to indicate what I understand from the given solution in the link I mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice linker.  Can't even interpret the error code for you?  Lame.  Anyway, `errno=2` is "access violation", which means you don't have permissions to write to or create the file `../../bin/mismatch`.

I can't say why that would be since I don't know what `../../bin` is on your system, but certainly changing it to `/usr/local/bin` won't help since you likely don't have write permissions to that directory either.

You can try just changing it to `-o mismatch` which will write out a file named `mismatch` in the current directory, which you most likely do have write permissions for.

BTW, your statement *-lm is used to link the executable to a library which I thought is "bin" here* is not correct.  `-lm` is asking the linker to link in the `m`, or math, library.  `bin` is not a library, it's a directory (or some people call them "folders"), and it has nothing to do with the argument `-lm`.

Comment: I was confused about `-lm`, thank you for the clarification! But then, what is role of the path `../../bin/mismatch` ? What is it required for? I also tried what you suggest, simply `-o mismatch`, but it didn't produce any results sadly.

Comment: The argument to the `-o` option tells the compiler or linker where to put the output.  If you say `-o foo` it writes the output to the current directory, as a file named `foo`.  If you say `-o ../../bin/mismatch` it writes the output to a file named `mismatch` in the directory `../../bin`, which means two levels up (each `..` means "parent directory") and then the `bin` directory.  So your current directory was something like `/Users/myself/src/some/dir` then `../../bin` would be `/Users/myself/src/bin` (two directories up, then `bin`).  Run `pwd` to see your current directory path.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _didn't produce any results_.  It has to have done something; either it produced a file or generated an error.  If you run `ls mismatch` what do you see?

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it makes much more sense. The problem is there was no 'bin' folder in the directory, so I created one. After that, "make" command worked very well! However, the arguments they advice to pass `./mismatch/mismatch 3 1 ${SFILE}` gave error again, saying mismatch is a directory which makes sense, and also they didn't mention 'bin' in their path! This is too torturing..

Comment: when I run `ls mismatch` it prints out `mismatch`, when I pass `./mismatch/mismatch 3 1 ${SFILE}` it again prints `mismatch` when it is supposed to list some similarity scores by comparing the sequences in ${FILE}.

Comment: Dale you have some confusion about directories, files, and pathnames and I don't think SO is the right place for learning that.  Try http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix1.html for example.  `mismatch` in your current directory (that is, `./mismatch`) can be _either_ a directory _or_ a file, but not both.  If it's a file, then running `./mismatch/mismatch` will give you an error because you can't have a file in a file.  If it's a directory then using `-o mismatch` on the compile line is bad because it wants to create a file and you gave it a directory.